# Ubuntu Server 18.04 graphics in console is extremely slow

Tags: drivers, server, 18.04, graphics, console

Hello,

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 to a server with Supermicro Motherboard X11SSH-TF with Graphics Aspeed AST2400 BMC build in and during boot up graphics get slow.

[I've recorded video example](https://youtu.be/6Rnqq61tECk).

During boot up is changed resolution (not possible to calibrate lcd) and everything is slowed down. LCD is connected with VGA cable (no other connector on motherboard).

When I tried to install Aspeed driver, this message is returned: `Can't find proper X Window Version, Please update driver manually!!`

Also Ubuntu Server installer was "bigger" than the screen.

Any idea?

dmesg:

```
[    9.593618] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[   11.182667] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[   11.182667] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[   12.141034]  sdb: sdb1
[   12.141037]  sda: sda1
[   12.141177] ata1.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[   12.144946] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] supports TCG Opal
[   12.144948] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   12.501827] ata2.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
[   12.576187] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] supports TCG Opal
[   12.644806] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   12.712732] dca service started, version 1.12.1
[   12.784242] ixgbe: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit PCI Express Network Driver - version 5.1.0-k
[   12.784676] [drm] Using P2A bridge for configuration
[   12.784687] [drm] AST 2400 detected
[   12.784777] [drm] Analog VGA only
[   12.784890] [drm] dram MCLK=408 Mhz type=1 bus_width=16 size=01000000
[   12.784953] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 16380210 kiB
[   12.784954] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 kiB
[   12.784954] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[   12.784964] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[   13.036775] checking generic (de000000 6c0000) vs hw (de000000 1000000)
[   13.036775] fb: switching to astdrmfb from VESA VGA
[   13.299132] md/raid1:md0: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
[   13.304440] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 499970473984
[   13.311544] random: fast init done
[   13.761199] ixgbe: Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Intel Corporation.
[   13.761261] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   13.761405] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   13.761455] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   13.761458] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[   13.761486] fbcon: astdrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   14.504339] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: Multiqueue Enabled: Rx Queue count = 8, Tx Queue count = 8 XDP Queue count = 0
[   14.547375] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: PCI Express bandwidth of 32GT/s available
[   14.547376] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: (Speed:8.0GT/s, Width: x4, Encoding Loss:<2%)
[   14.576058] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: MAC: 4, PHY: 0, PBA No: 020A00-000
[   14.576059] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: ac:1f:6b:6a:a8:7e
[   14.741565] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
[   15.304828] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[   15.483836] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: Multiqueue Enabled: Rx Queue count = 8, Tx Queue count = 8 XDP Queue count = 0
[   15.526960] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: PCI Express bandwidth of 32GT/s available
[   15.526961] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: (Speed:8.0GT/s, Width: x4, Encoding Loss:<2%)
[   15.555653] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: MAC: 4, PHY: 0, PBA No: 020A00-000
[   15.555654] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: ac:1f:6b:6a:a8:7f
[   15.720304] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1: Intel(R) 10 Gigabit Network Connection
[   15.721062] ixgbe 0000:04:00.1 eno2: renamed from eth1
[   16.847126] ast 0000:03:00.0: fb0: astdrmfb frame buffer device
[   16.868358] [drm] Initialized ast 0.1.0 20120228 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 0
[   16.904552] ixgbe 0000:04:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[   18.796028] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 13982 MB/s
[   18.844037] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  9906 MB/s
[   18.892035] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 16623 MB/s
[   18.940034] raid6: sse2x2   xor() 11083 MB/s
[   18.988033] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 19519 MB/s
[   19.036037] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 12315 MB/s
[   19.084027] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 27847 MB/s
[   19.132027] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 17879 MB/s
[   19.180027] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 32031 MB/s
[   19.228027] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 19091 MB/s
[   19.276027] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 38101 MB/s
[   19.324027] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 24201 MB/s
[   19.324035] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 38101 MB/s
[   19.324046] raid6: .... xor() 24201 MB/s, rmw enabled
[   19.324068] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[   19.324897] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
[   19.325431] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[   19.436594] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
[   20.396339] EXT4-fs (md0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   22.961498] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   22.966175] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[   22.984181] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[   25.507486] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <server>.
[   25.571535] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   28.920621] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   30.789892] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   32.659232] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   34.533482] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   36.416057] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   38.289899] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[   40.165592] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   42.045067] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[   43.926966] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[   45.810510] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   47.696070] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[   49.596305] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[   51.488378] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[   53.390141] systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
[   55.294611] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
```

Comment: I work around 1,000s of servers everyday.  Supermicro's happen to be one type that I work around.   Servers are not meant as graphical systems on their video cards and the higher the resolution the slower they get on screen refresh.  I am not at work right now to look at possible kernel lines to keep the resolution lower.  Let me look at some stuff on these and I will get back to you.

Comment: Everything working fine in text mode until (I suppose) video driver is switched to "ast".

Comment: I guess you could try uncommenting the line of `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` from the `/etc/default/grub` file then run the `sudo update-grub` and try the reboot again so that the graphical doesn't try switching on you.

Comment: Thanks, but not worked. The screen looks the same (text has same small size and starts off the screen). Screenshot: https://s33.postimg.cc/9z9upchz3/IMG_2282.jpg

Comment: One other thing I can think of off the top of my head to try is to change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` in the `/etc/default/grub` file.  Then update grub and reboot again.

Comment: Appended also `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`. This combination changed initial state of booting. But after `ast` driver load everything has returned to its original (wrong) state.

Comment: Looks like we might be missing the GFXPAYLOAD as well that might have to be added to the `/etc/default/grub` file.  See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ChangeTTYResolution

Comment: I think we are on the wrong way. In my opinion is needed to disable wrong driver or install newer version... Because until driver load is everything okay.

Comment: I don't recall ever loading a driver on the servers.  This should in no way affect the speed of the server itself though.  We normally access all our servers from an SSH session in terminal at 80x24 and they always seem to work fine.  I guess you could try removing the driver then.

Comment: Partial solution for me was:
`sudo vim /etc/default/grub` uncomment `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`, then `sudo update-grub`.

Next disable `ast` driver: `sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, append line `blacklist ast`, then `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot.

System boot is now significantly faster.